# Scanner Ignores Some Inputs (System.in)

Tags: java, input, stream

I've recently come along this frustrating problem, where the scanner completely ignores some inputs from the System.in inputstream. Here's an example:

```
Do you want a cookie? Yes or no.
```

Now, I type yes:

```
yes
```

Result:

```
Cookie for you!
```

Now, if I say no:

```
no
no
```

Result:

```
No Cookie for you.
```

Get it? If I say yes it just accepts it. If I say no, I have to type it 2 times.

If you really need some code. Here's some of that :)

```
public static void main(String[] paramArgs){
    MainEW sMain = new MainEW();
    Scanner s = sMain.scanner;

    System.out.println("Enter a file path.");
    System.out.println("Example: /Users/Some_User/Desktop/Some_Folder");
    String defPath = s.next();

    System.out.println("Enter a name for the file.");
    String defName = s.next() + ".txt";

    System.out.println("Now, enter what you want to write to the file.");
    s.nextLine();
    String defText = s.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Do you want to create a new file? Yes or No");

    if (s.next().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        WriterEW writer = new WriterEW(defPath, defName, defText, true);
        return;
    } else if (s.next().equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        WriterEW writer = new WriterEW(defPath, defName, defText, false);
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can't find `Cookie` in your code!!!

Comment: I do realize that xP. It's the same thing with what I use now though.

Comment: And why the hell do you downvote my post just for that :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you type "no", the `else if` block calls `next()` again, asking for more input.

Instead of calling `s.next()` in each case, call it just once before you start your `if` conditions.

```
String response = s.next();
if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
    WriterEW writer = new WriterEW(defPath, defName, defText, true);
    return;
}else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
```

Comment: Okay, I get what you're trying to tell me. But as you can see in my code. I'm not actually asking for an input, until I actually call my if statements... Shouldn't that do the trick?

Comment: In your code, your `if` condition asks for input by calling `s.next()`.  You type "no", which doesn't equal "yes", so the `else if` code runs next.  Then the `else if` condition asks for input again by calling `s.next()` also.  You type "no" again, which does equal "no", so the `else if` block runs.

Comment: I actually thought that if code actually runs (in the if statement) if  its actually true xD

Comment: No, the code in the `if` condition always runs.  It's the following block that won't run if the condition is `false`.